Why doesn't the operator precedence "work" with ++/-- i C#?
According to C#'s operator precedence, ++/-- is high on the list (above arithmetic like +, -, etc).
This made me believe that if I had a code looking like this:
int a = 2;
int b = a++;

b "should have" been assigned the value 3 because incrementing is above assignment in the operator precedence list. Why isn't the increment done before assignment?

I don't understand "why does it save the ++ to the end on the second line?". What result do you get and what you expect?

honestly: if you ever need to care about operator precedence, the code is unclear; I literally never worry about operator precedence (outside of trivial things like ++i vs i++ in an argument) : if it will be at all unclear to me or some future reader (which could be future me): add parentheses, and move on with my day. The compiler doesn't care how "clever" you are.

There is a reason it is called postincrement. It increments "after" ...

Fiddle. Results: "a = 4, b = 7, c = -1". Now what is your question?

The precedence of evaluating the operator is a separate concern from what the operator does.  You appear to be confusing the two.  Instead of asking very generally "why doesn't this work" or "why does this produce this result", present a specific example and indicate what result you observe, what result you expected, and most importantly why you expected that result.  Be sure to also research and investigate/test what these operators do in the first place.

The problem seems to be a misunderstanding of a++. The results are exactly what the precedence rules say they should be. Postincrement means increment after - in this case after using the value. b=a++; is equivalent to b=a; a=a+1;

It feels like you're confusing operator precendence with the difference between ++a and a++. The assignment operator is definitely last - the difference is what the ++ operator returns in each case.

Meaning, it seems like in b = a++ you believe the assignment is happening before the increment. That is false. The increment operator is returning the original value of a, then assigning that to b. By the time the value is assigned to b, a has already been incremented.

The result of post-increment (a++) is the value before increment while the result of pre-increment is the value after increment.
int a = 2; int b = a++; int c = ++a;

Here a++ gives 2 to b, but new value of a is 3. Then another new value 4 of a comes to c.
The next functions can help to understand:
int PostIncrement(ref int a) {
  int b = a; a = a + 1; return b;
}

int PreIncrement(ref int a) {
  a = a + 1; return a;
}

// and

int a = 2;
int b = PostIncrement(ref a);
int c = PreIncrement(ref a);

Then in
int a = 2;
int b = a++ + 5;
int c = ++a - 5;

pre-increment and post-increment execute first, + and - second, and assignment last as prescribed.
Pre-increment or post-increment takes the neighbour operand only.
So, more detailed, the execution order in b = a++ + 5 is:

a++
(1) + 5
b = (2)


I wonder what question do you answer, can you perhaps put it in the beginning of answer? I feel dumb.

I second Sinatr. Question is about operator precedence, however there might also be a misconception of how pre/post increment works. But I am missing the former part in the answer.

Definitely! Modified.

You've got your pre-increment and post-increment (both the functions and the descriptions) backwards. ++a returns the value AFTER the increment, not before. Ex, int x = 2; return ++x returns 3.
